# How to solve a 4th degree polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I am feeling difficulty to find the roots of this 4th degree polynomial:

$3x^4+26x^3+77x^2+84x+24=0$

Factorization methods have been tried.

Comment: [Why](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E4%2B26x%5E3%2B77x%5E2%2B84x%2B24%3D0) do you ask?

Answer (score 2):

There are two real roots, and two complex roots to your polynomial.  Even the real roots are rather complicated. They do *not* lend themselves to any sort of nice factoring.

You can estimate the roots by graphing the polynomial, and zeroing in at the intersection points of the graph with the $x$-axis,

[image]

or use graphing software like Wolfram Alpha to give [exact forms for the solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%5E4%2b26x%5E3%2b77x%5E2%2b84x%2b24=0).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have seen the plot of the function and noticed that it is well conditioned in the area of the roots, you can apply a Newton method which writes
x_new = x_old - f(x_old) / f'(x_old)
Suppose we start with x_old = -1.5, the successive iterates will then be -1.6094 and -1.6097; you can continue this process until you meet the required accuracy.
Suppose we start with x_old = -0.5, the successive iterates will then be -0.4275, -0.4348 and -0.4349; you can continue this process until you meet the required accuracy.
The approximate solutions are -1.60971770887 and -0.434922318772; these are the numerical values of the nice expressions posted by Oliver Bel